# Regulating step speed in game

Tags: java, math, game-physics

I am developing a game and I need to create a method to create a movement. What it needs to do is take `x y` and `target x y` values and create a `float[]` with the movement inside of it defined to a certain time. The movement will be used every frame for a certain amount of frames until it has reached the target in a specific time. Here is what I have so far.

```
public void calculateRoute(int time) {
    if(x > tx){
        movement[0] = -((x - tx) / time);
    }else if(x < tx){
        movement[0] = ((tx - x) / time);
    }else if(x == tx){
        movement[0] = 0;
    }

    if(y > ty){
        movement[1] = -((y - ty) / time);
    }else if(y < ty){
        movement[1] = ((ty - y) / time);
    }else if(y == ty){
        movement[1] = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the farther the target, the quicker the movement is. I want to have the movement regulating to a certain speed but still reach its target. Basically I need to calculate the `time` variable to a speed that will always be the same, no matter the distance. I tried this with setting the movement to 1 but it would miss its target since `x` could be 500, and the `y` could be 700. It would end up being `x = 700, y = 700`. Any help is appreciated! :)

Also some sample code would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

1. In today's multi-core, multi-tasking computers you cannot reliably predict how much time will elapse between each rendered frame or each logic/physics/AI update.
2. As you've discovered with your solution, your speed calculation is based on distance, when it needs to be some **units moved per unit of time** (perhaps pixels/second, or blocks/second - whatever unit of measure makes sense in your game).
3. When you're moving things around in your world, it's often best to measure the time elapsed since the last time you moved things around, and then multiply the time elapsed by your speed, because `speed*time=distance moved`

If you're using a game engine, which would be a really good idea because this is a solved problem, they will provide some kind of "delta" time that tells you how much time has elapsed since the last logic/physics/AI update. You can use that value.

- [Here's an explanation of how deltaTime works in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html), a popular game engine these days
- [Here's some sample code I wrote in Java that uses Slick2D](https://github.com/jefflunt/pedestrians/blob/master/src/com/jefflunt/pedestrians/Pedestrian.java#L226), but the concept is the same in any game/game engine.

Comment: The time doesn't matter too much. I just want the movement to be calculated per the different hypotenuse. The movement is pixels/frane where my game is regulated to anout 60fps

Comment: But because of #1, you can't do pixels/frame. You will not, ever, get exactly 60fps. If you haven't discovered this yet [you soon will](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jittery+game+movement), and what you'll wind up with is jittery movements because of the slight variations in frame timing. No one really gets 60.0 fps consistently (16.6ms per frame). You'll get jitter like `[16.5, 13.0, 20.2, 16.4, ...]` etc., where you might render a **total** of 60 frames in 1000 milliseconds, but the time between each frame will NOT be consistent. This is a fundamental, common, but incorrect assumption.

Comment: The "jitter" doesn't really matter to me. I am using a nano timer and the time in between frames is consistent enough because I factor in the delta time.

Comment: The nano timer won't eliminate the jitter. The jitter is caused by not being able to know when your code will actually execute, since the thread in which it runs is scheduled by the OS, and not directly under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're asking is, given:

- a `distance` between point A and point B
- a fixed distance per step let's call this `stepSize`

You want to have in a `float []`:

One element for every step it will take to travel `distance`, one `stepSize` at a time. So:

```
stepSize = speed / 60.0;   // 60 fps
stepCount = distance / stepSize;
```

Then a for loop that goes from 0 to stepCount-1, moving stepSize distance on each step.

I don't know what you need a float[] for in that case. If your step size doesn't evenly divide the distance you need to travel, and on the last step you've overshot you're target a bit, then on the last step simply set the (x, y) to the target (x, y)